# Codeigniter delete record from table where page_id and user_id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multiple-conditions

I have a database were users can make multiple pages, as shown in the image below.[image]

I'm using codeigniter MVC, I would like to allow users to delete their pages.

So if `page_id = 1` is being passed by `user_id =1` for deleting, only the row in the table for user_id=1 and page_id = 1 should be deleted.

Here is my `model_page.php` code so far but all the pages for user_id 1 is deleting

```
function delete_user_page($user_id, $page_id){

    $query = $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id and 'page_id', $page_id);
    return $this->db->delete('mysql_table');

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function delete_user_page($user_id, $page_id){
    $cond  = ['user_id' => $user_id, 'page_id' => $page_id];
    $query = $this->db->where($cond);
    return $this->db->delete('mysql_table');
}
```

Logic is that we need to make an array of all list of parameters.

Comment: This is perfect! very clean with good practice! thanks Naveed

Comment: I clicked the accept tick in the first 5 min, strange.. I did it now anyway, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Either

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM mysql_table WHERE user_id = ? AND page_id = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($user_id, $page_id));
```

OR

```
$this->db->delete('mysql_table', array('user_id' => $user_id,'page_id' => $user_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use associative array method::

```
function delete_user_page($user_id, $page_id)
{
    $where_cond = ['user_id' => $user_id, 'page_id' => $page_id];
    return $this->db->delete('mysql_table', $where_cond);
}
// DELETE FROM mysql_table WHERE user_id = $id AND page_id = $page_id
```

Looking for Specific Data:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Deleting Data:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data